# Shouldn't there be a comma added after Monet in "An impressionist painter, Monet depicted water lilies in many of his works of art."

Tags: commas

[image]

So as you can see, it asks for a complete sentence. However, the correct answer, in my opinion, is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: If this were the first mention of Monet in a piece of writing, I agree with you that it would be more common (and arguably more appropriate) to treat _Monet_ as an appositive, with commas fore and aft. But if, one sentence earlier, the writer had written something like "In this essay I want to say a few things about Claude Monet," the single-comma treatment in the sentence you quote would be perfectly normal and reasonable. So the answer to your question about whether one comma or two is more normal, more common, or more correct is that it depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

You could put a comma there and get:

> An impressionistic painter, Monet, depicted water lilies in many of his works of art.

Howvever, here *Monet* serves as "additional information" to *an impressionistic painter*--and this phrase is the sentence's subject. It seems like the speaker doesn't really care about mentioning the actual name of the artist, just that it happens to be Monet instead of another impressionistic artist.

Whereas in

> An impressionistic painter, Monet depicted water lilies in many of his works of art.

Monet is a center stage; he is the subject of the sentence; he is what the sentence is talking about. The opening phrase *an impressionistic painter* gives more information about him. You could also place this phrase after his name:

> Monet, an impressionistic painter, depicted water lilies in many of his works of art.

and in this case you need to set off the phrase with commas on both sides of it. You can't do this when the phrase comes at the start of the sentence unless you want to write

> ,An impressionistic painter, Monet depicted water lilies in many of his works of art.

which style of writing is not utilized by 99.99999% of writers.

Comment: Very nice and detailed answer, upvote! I appreciate this because you have covered all the aspects of the matter, giving us some interesting ideas how the same sentence could be written in different styles to convey different nuances of meaning.